# Elasticsearch NEST with Where condition

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to `MultiMatch` search with a condition. I know similar questions have been asked in the past but not with using `NEST`. This is my current search, it works well across the entire document

```
 var response = await this.client.SearchAsync<EmployeeDocument>(
                               x => x.Index(this.settings.IndexName).Type("employee").From(page * pageSize)
                                   .Size(pageSize).Query(
                                       q => q.MultiMatch(m => m
                                                .Query(query)
                                                .Type(TextQueryType.MostFields)
                                                .MinimumShouldMatch("90%")
                                                .Fields(f => f
                                                    .Field(_ => _.FullName, 3)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.Number, 3)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.Email)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.CompanyName, 2)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.JobNumber)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.Description))))
                    .Highlight(
                        h => h.PreTags("<mark>").PostTags("</mark>")
                            .Fields(
                                f => f.Field(p => p.FullName),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.CompanyName),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.JobNumber),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.Number),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.Email),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.Description))));
```

How can I add a condition too only search for a specific field? `(CompanyId)`

So for instance the above code does an employee search, but it only needs to search inside a specific company.

This is what i have tried

```
var response = await this.client.SearchAsync<EmployeeDocument>(
                               x => x.Index(this.settings.IndexName).Type("employee").From(page * pageSize)
                                   .Size(pageSize).Query(
                                       q => q.MultiMatch(m => m
                                                .Query(query)
                                                .Type(TextQueryType.MostFields)
                                                .MinimumShouldMatch("90%")
                                                .Fields(f => f
                                                    .Field(_ => _.FullName, 3)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.Number, 3)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.Email)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.CompanyName, 2)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.JobNumber)
                                                    .Field(_ => _.Description))))
                           .Query(_ => _.Bool(b => b.Must(descriptor =>
                                       descriptor.Term(t => 
t.Field(document => document.CompanyGroupId).Value(4213))))) // I ADDED THIS SECTION HERE
                    .Highlight(
                        h => h.PreTags("<mark>").PostTags("</mark>")
                            .Fields(
                                f => f.Field(p => p.FullName),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.CompanyName),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.JobNumber),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.Number),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.Email),
                                f => f.Field(p => p.Description))));
```

I added the extra query to do the `bool` condition but I does not seem to return the correct output. But I am sure my `NEST` query is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to construct a `bool` query with a `must` and `filter` clause. Using [operator overloading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#_operator_overloading) on queries, this can be expressed more succinctly

```
var query = "query";
var page = 1;
var pageSize = 10;

var searchResponse = client.Search<EmployeeDocument>(x => x
    .Index("indexName")
    .Type("employee")
    .From(page * pageSize)
    .Size(pageSize)
    .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(m => m
            .Query(query)
            .Type(TextQueryType.MostFields)
            .MinimumShouldMatch("90%")
            .Fields(f => f
                .Field(ff => ff.FullName, 3)
                .Field(ff => ff.Number, 3)
                .Field(ff => ff.Email)
                .Field(ff => ff.CompanyName, 2)
                .Field(ff => ff.JobNumber)
                .Field(ff => ff.Description)
            )
        ) && +q
        .Term(f => f.CompanyGroupId, 4213)
    )
    .Highlight(h => h
        .PreTags("<mark>")
        .PostTags("</mark>")
        .Fields(
            f => f.Field(p => p.FullName),
            f => f.Field(p => p.CompanyName),
            f => f.Field(p => p.JobNumber),
            f => f.Field(p => p.Number),
            f => f.Field(p => p.Email),
            f => f.Field(p => p.Description)
        )
    )
);
```

which yields the following request

```
{
  "from": 10,
  "size": 10,
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<mark>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</mark>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "fullName": {},
      "companyName": {},
      "jobNumber": {},
      "number": {},
      "email": {},
      "description": {}
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "type": "most_fields",
            "query": "query",
            "minimum_should_match": "90%",
            "fields": [
              "fullName^3",
              "number^3",
              "email",
              "companyName^2",
              "jobNumber",
              "description"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "companyGroupId": {
              "value": 4213
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, let me quickly have look